# Attaching referal code with google play link

Tags: android

I am currently facing an issue.
I want to refer an app for many of my clients. But there's a huge problem.
This is my referral link, I am sending to my clients when they install their app using this link:

Referral field should be automatically filled:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/L7VBU.jpg)

https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.msf.angelmobile&referrer=a1058095::rne_source=rne_app_abma::rne_field2=rne_client7

But I want this to open directly in google play store. So I'm trying

https://play.app.goo.gl/?link=https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.msf.angelmobile&referrer=a1058095::rne_source=rne_app_abma::rne_field2=rne_client7

This is just giving me a problem that Referral field in app is not filled automatically.

Can anyone help me out?

Comment: The Google Play Store is not gonna facilitate this for you. Rather, what you should do is implement deep links in your app. That way, users can click a deep link which your app 'listens' to, after which you can show the page with the referral code. There is no mechanism in place for "configured installations" from clicking on a Google Play Store link.

Comment: @nbokmans App is not mine. Can I still generate a deep link?